# how can i make one web application access my own web service(asp.net)?

Tags: asp.net

I have web service asp.Net and i want only one specific web application uses it, but I can't do this .

can any one tell me how i can solve this problem .

Comment: What is the exact problem? No access? Errors? Exceptions? Provide as much pertinent information as possible, as at the moment your question in too vague to answer.

Comment: I think he's asking how to prevent people discovering and using a web service he's publishing.

Comment: I need some body tell me how can i make only this web application access my web service without changing anything in web application code , I want to know the request URL if the request come from this web application okay , web service , reply for this request 
other requests , i need my web service do not reply

Answer (score 1):

### Authentication solution

You can protect your methods by using the password as the argument in each of them, or in a better scenario use traditional forms authentication to authorize user (in this case your application) and then check if the user is logged while invoking webmethods.

For example crate authorize method like this:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public bool Authorize(login, password)
{
   if(login == "admin" && password == "supersecret")
   {
      FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login, false);
      return true;
   }

   return false;
}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)
public string SomeWebMethod()
{
   if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     throw Exception("User unathenticated");

   /* method body */
}
```

Then you can use your webservice by invoking `Authorize` method just once at the start of using it, and then use all methods you like because authentication info is stored in the webservice providing server session.

Do not forget to set `EnableSession` to true in all your webmethods.

### IP comparing solution

In your webservice put a method

```
public bool CanExecute()
{
   return Context.Request.UserHostAddress == "290.110.11.12" /* put real ip here */    
}
```

then in your webmethods use

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)
public string SomeWebMethod()
{
   if(!CanExecute())
     throw Exception("User unathenticated");

   /* method body */
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: But , if i need no change in the web application , if i authenticate the web service with password may any one get this password or the owner of this web application can pass it to other people , so i search for any other solution to go far from modifying any thing at web application

Comment: Okay, if you can't change your app then my idea is not suitable to your problem... Please be more precise next time. Still it's okay if you want to use this solution someday... Greetings..

Comment: I use authorization but do u have any other solution , Like how can i get the ip or url that the request come from

Comment: I need to ask you , what is your opinion to take the sign of this web application is it realistic? web application mean changes in every time

Comment: What do you mean by "sing of this web app" ??

Comment: Take the Signature of the web application code and store it in my web service and in every request , he will send me this signature and i will check it first , then if this signature is the same that i have return the true result , if not ,then i'll return invalid request

Comment: sign mean i take the all codes and make a function in it and it will generate a signature for this specific code .

Comment: No.. it's definitely bad idea ;)

Comment: I've added IP comparing solution for you.. Hipe it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the IP address of the only computer that is allowed to use your webservice, you can check for it and either return a 404 or an exception if it isn't.

Comment: can you give me the code that return the ip address to place it in my code ?